# Does V4L2 have any functions like libusb_control_transfer()?

Tags: c++, c, camera, v4l2

I try to send/receive data to/from camera registers in Ubuntu 20.04,
and want to use V4L2 to control what I mentioned.
My question is, does V4L2 have any functions like libusb_control_transfer()?

The parameters of libusb_control_transfer() are below,

```
libusb_control_transfer (libusb_device_handle* dev_handle,
uint8_t bmRequestType,
uint8_t bRequest,
uint16_t wValue,
uint16_t wIndex,
unsigned char* data,
uint16_t wLength,
unsigned int timeout
)
```

You can also refer https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/group__libusb__syncio.html.

Thanks for help.